# Add a Navigation Term Set in a Site Definition

Tags: 2013, term-store, site-definition

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I am trying to provision a new site with an initial term set used for navigation.

I was thinking i could use Visual Studio & create a Site Definition--similar to using `<NavBars>` in onet.xml. Is there an equivalent for using managed metadata instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here. It speaks to using Term sets for global navigation.

Overview of managed navigation in SharePoint Server 2013
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section1

You can find step by step instructions here:

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/07/20/sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata-term-store-aspx/

You can implement these changes post deployment of your site definition.

https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/programmatically-creating-group-termset-and-term-in-manage-metadata-service-in-sharepoint-2013/

You can also create these with code.

Comment: Duly Noted Good Sir...Updating now.

Comment: I'm not sure now to add the terms to my site definition. Maybe I'm completely off base. Is there something I need to add to onet.xml?

Comment: Markus, you're wanting to create a new term store with terms using code?

Comment: Yes. I apologize if i am not being clear. Let me update the question.

Comment: Just updated my answer with another link. Let me know if it helps.